# Does Crystal Report Support Printing In Chrome?

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, crystal-reports

We have a legacy system that's based on Java EE and Crystal Report. The problem is, printing option only works in IE. In Chrome or Firefox, when clicking Print button, it opens Print To PDF dialog.

I suspect that the problem is with ActiveX technology that crystal report viewer use for it's functionality.

So, I'm wondering if crystal reports supports using other technologies such as Flash or Applets. And if so, where can I find some documentation about it.